# How to preserve path params after handling a request with router.Any and wildcard

Tags: http, go, go-gin

In my case need to catch request and check is internal request or not. If not, redirect these request to other handler function.

URL example:

```
1. URL: http://localhost/internal/dosomething1
2. URL: http://localhost/internal/dosomething2/:id
3. URL: http://localhost/overview
4. URL: http://localhost/xxx
```

Only the URIs that start with `internal` should be handled in my own handle function (cases 1 and 2).

Others with any request method will proxy to another function (cases 3 and 4).

I am trying to use `router.Any("/*uri", handlerExternal)` as such:

```
func handlerExternal(c *gin.Context) {
    path := c.Param("uri")
    if strings.HasPrefix(path, "/internal/") {

        uri := strings.Split(path, "/")
        switch uri[2] {
        case "dosomething1":
            doInternal(c)
        }
    } else {
        doExternal(c)
    }
}
```

But with this solution, the `doInternal(c)` cannot catch path parameters like `:id` as in `http://localhost/internal/dosomething2/:id`

Is there any better solution for this case?

Comment: In your example the `/internal` path appears to be the first path segment after host, so you could declare `router.Any("/internal", ...)`, couldn't you?

Comment: @blackgreen panic: '/internal/' in new path '/internal/' conflicts with existing wildcard '/*uri' in existing prefix '/*uri'

Comment: ok, so you want to keep using wildcard, catch `internal` routes in the main handler, and preserve path parameters in the sub-handlers. RIght?

Comment: Yes, keep catch `internal` and parse parameters and parse payload. But also catch others except `internal`, to redirect to another service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a sub-engine.

You can instantiate an engine with `gin.New` for internal routes only **and not run it**. Instead you pass the context from your `Any` route to [`Engine.HandleContext`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Engine.HandleContext).

This will relay the context from the main engine, and it will match path params based on the placeholders in the sub-routes.

You can declare routes on the sub-engine as usual:

```
func main() {
    internalEngine := gin.New()
    internalEngine.GET("/internal/dosomething1", func(c *gin.Context) { c.JSON(200, "ok") })
    internalEngine.GET("/internal/dosomething2/:id", func(c *gin.Context) { c.JSON(200, c.Param("id")) })

    mainEngine := gin.New()
    mainEngine.Any("/*uri", func(c *gin.Context) {
        path := c.Param("uri")
        if strings.HasPrefix(path, "/internal/") {
            uri := strings.Split(path, "/")
            switch uri[2] {
            case "dosomething1", "dosomething2":
                internalEngine.HandleContext(c)
            }
        } else {
            doExternal(c)
        }
    })
    mainEngine.Run(":8800")
}
```

You can also modify `c.Request.URL.Path` before relaying the context to the sub-engine, e.g. by removing the `internal` prefix, if so you wish.

Now if you try a GET request to:

```
http://localhost:8855/internal/dosomething2/1234
```

it will echo the output:

```
"1234"
```